# how to create a flag in Apex?

Tags: apex

I need to create a flag to identify when the permanent address is different from the temporary address.

I would appreciate if someone can explain me what this flag is. I understand is a Boolean operation insert in the Apex code but not sure how to do it or how it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this a few different ways:

1. (Recommended) Create a formula field with a return type of "checkbox" to act as a flag indicating equality/inequality of two fields. The formula would simply be field_A = field_B.
2. Create a workflow rule on the object containing the two fields and create a new text field on that object (don't use a checkbox). Select the option to run when a record is created and every time it's updated. Under "rule criteria" have it run when a formula evaluates to true and make the formula "true" so that it will always run. Add an action to the workflow rule to perform a field update. Select your new field as the field to update and select "use a formula to set the new value". The formula will be "IF(field_A=field_B, '1', '0')".
3. Create a trigger that runs before update and before insert and compares the field values in trigger.new. Save the result to a new custom field.

I recommend option 1 here because it's easy to setup even for a non-developer and no changeset or test class is required to deploy it to production.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way, if you want to check on client side you can check variable comparison on validation and set the variable flag, second way you can write function while running insert operation if same insert flag as Y.

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger for your object and in the trigger do this:

```
trigger objcetname on objectname__c (before insert, before update)
{
   for(objectname__c myObj :trigger.new)
   {
      if(myObj.permanentAddress != tempAddress)
      {
           // do what you have to do here!!
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flag is custom formula field which return as checkbox whether the permanent address is different from temporary address